# Combining URLs with & without subdomain prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, no-www

On the root of my hosting account sit two important folders: `httpdocs` and `subdomains`
Now in order to silently load page `index.htm` for all four of the domainvariations (below) I'm stuck in that bits n pieces from other answers don't join up well together to make it work:

```
    team.bravo.org
         bravo.org
www.team.bravo.org
     www.bravo.org
```

the server folder structure:

```
/httpdocs/
   index.htm
   .htaccess       [1]

/subdomains/
   /team/
      .htaccess    [2]

   /www.team/
      .htaccess    [3]
```

---

In .htacces [1] siting in the httpdocs folder currently all non-www gets nicely redirected to www using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

What needs to go to the the first, second and third '.htaccess'file to make all domains to redirect permanently to `team.bravo.org` and load `index.htm`?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming mod_alias is available on your server (just try this first and see if it works), you could put this in each `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect permanent / http://team.bravo.org/
```

Otherwise, this is a mod_rewrite solution:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://team.bravo.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```